# I am not able to connect to mysql via ssh and I don't know why using Java

Tags: java, mysql, ssh, tunnel

Ok - so I have been working on this for some time (sometimes not working on it), and I am ALMOST there but not yet. I am trying to tunnel into a mysql db and was able to successfully connect ssh using Jsch. But when I try to connect to the database, it gives me an "Access denied for user 'usernamne'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Here is the following code: (of course I masked out sensitive info)

```
public void connect(){
    String user = "user";
    String password = "password";
    String host = "host.com";
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        Connection conn = null;
        Properties info = new Properties();

        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
        jsch.addIdentity("/Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa", password);

        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        System.out.println("Establishing Connection...");
        if(session.isConnected()){
            session.disconnect();
        }
        session.connect();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:4417/dbname","dbuser", "dbpassword");
        System.out.print("Connection successful!" + "\n\n");
        System.out.print("Connection:" + conn + "\n\n");

        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM TABLENAME limit 1");
        System.out.print(resultSet);
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSchException j){
        j.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

I've read other posts on here but I have not found the exact solution to my problem. I am able to ssh in correct. And what's even more interesting is that if I do the same exact procedure command_line, it works fine. So I don't know why it wouldn't work here.

Comment: You are requesting a connection on your own machine. Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: If I am not wrong it seems you are trying to do db call over ssh(port forwarding).
If so then it needs to done in firewall configuration. Here you are doing ssh in java, but finally when calling db connection it will create direct database connection.

Comment: Yes I am trying to create a conn from my own machine.

Comment: ok @starlord I am trying to do a db call over ssh (port forwarding). It needs to be done in firewall configuration? I am not sure what you mean? Are there any references you can point me to that I can take a look at? I've never had to do this type of connection. My previous experience was .net and it was straightforward - thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this. it might help you . Already tested in my setup. Enjoy. :)

## create db user in remote mysql db.

CREATE USER 'myuser'@'clientip' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';

CREATE USER 'myuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';

grant ALL ON mydb.* to 'myuser'@'clientip';

grant ALL ON mydb.* to 'myuser'@'%';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

---

Code for ssh tunneling.

```
    int assigned_port;   
    final int local_port=8080;

    // Remote host and port
    final int remote_port=3306;
    final String remote_host="192.168.150.139";

    try {
        JSch jsch = new JSch(); 

        // Create SSH session.  Port 22 is your SSH port which
        // is open in your firewall setup.
        session = jsch.getSession("sshuser", remote_host, 22);
        session.setPassword("sshpassword");

        // Additional SSH options.  See your ssh_config manual for
        // more options.  Set options according to your requirements.
        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        config.put("Compression", "yes");
        config.put("ConnectionAttempts","2");

        session.setConfig(config);

        // Connect
        session.connect();            

        // Create the tunnel through port forwarding.  
        // This is basically instructing jsch session to send 
        // data received from local_port in the local machine to 
        // remote_port of the remote_host
        // assigned_port is the port assigned by jsch for use,
        // it may not always be the same as
        // local_port.

        assigned_port = session.setPortForwardingL(local_port, 
                remote_host, remote_port);

    } catch (JSchException e) {            
        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage()); return;
    }

    if (assigned_port == 0) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Port forwarding failed !"); 
        return;
    }

    // Database access credentials.  Make sure this user has
    // "connect" access to this database;

    // these may be initialized somewhere else in your code.
    final String database_user="myuser";
    final String database_password="pass";
    final String database = "mydb";

    // Build the  database connection URL.
    StringBuilder url =
            new StringBuilder("jdbc:mysql://localhost:");

    // use assigned_port to establish database connection
    url.append(assigned_port).append ("/").append(database).append ("?user=").
            append(database_user).append ("&password=").
            append (database_password);

    try {
        Class.forName(
                "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        System.out.println(url.toString());
        java.sql.Connection connection =
                java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(url.toString());

       String q="select * from customer";
       PreparedStatement ps=connection.prepareStatement(q);
       ResultSet rs= ps.executeQuery();
       while (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+rs.getString(2));
    }


    } catch (ClassNotFoundException |
            java.sql.SQLException e) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        session.disconnect();
    }
```

Comment: I will try this.  When I attempted to edit the my.cnf file, after reviewing some posts to possibly configure the bind-address to 0.0.0.0, I cannot make any edits because it is not owned by me. So my suspicion is that I cannot make any types of edits because I do not have any administrative privileges to make such changes.